Temperature and rainfall data for London
I'm looking for temperature and rainfall data for London, for the period June-July-August 2022. Ideally, I'd like a point shapefile otherwise a csv containing an x and y (coordinates) columns.
I've checked Met Office but I couldn't find them.
